# What makes valid a philosophy of success?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

In his [Think and Grow Rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_and_Grow_Rich), Napoleon Hill talks about his philosophy of success. In this book he exposes a set of principles that encompasses a lifetime work of investigation of what makes some people successful. His book is arguable the most successful motivational book. So would that make it a valid philosophy of success regardless of its soundness?

Comment: It seems "philosophy of success" uses "philosophy" in the colloquial sense of personal philosophy, not in the academic sense understood on this site. It is also unclear what you mean by "valid philosophy" or "soundness". One can certainly adopt a [pragmatic theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatic_theory_of_truth) according to which a belief is true if it is useful to hold it. Do you want it assessed from some particular other perspective?

Comment: @Conifold Yes, [pragmatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatism) would be perfectly applicable in this case, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Conifold  I am not sure of that.  Aristotle's notion of happiness seems to be another word for success.  So at least some philosophies of success have been serious academic endeavors.

Comment: @rraallvv , also, this has nothing to do with philosophy of mind, which you added in the tags , philosophy of mind is very different.